# RxNet Pagination

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

**Update: Signature and Type Definitions**

*GetChecklistStringParents*

```
IObservable<ChecklistStringParents_Response> GetChecklistStringParents(int company_id, string auth_token, string q = null, int page = 1)
```

*Top level response representing a page*

```
public class ChecklistStringParents_Response
{
    //the content of the page a list of string parents
    public List<Resp_ChecklistStringParent> BODY { get; set; }
    public Resp_Meta META { get; set; }
    public List<object> ERRORS { get; set; }
}
```

*Response class for a single string parent*

```
public class Resp_ChecklistStringParent
{
    public int checklist_string_type { get; set; }
    public string client_date_created { get; set; }
    public string uploaded_date { get; set; }
    public string last_modified { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to reactively (RxNet) access a REST API I've built, however I'm very new to the paradigm and am a bit stuck.

The following function requests data from a endpoint page by page.

`Observable.DoWhile` and `Observable.Defer` are used so that a new observable is created for each page, and we keep creating them until we receive an empty list 
as the body of the page response.

I am subscribing to the observable returned by `Observable.DoWhile` to update the page and to update the result count. This doesn't feel right, but I've not seen an alternative.

My question is, is this the best way to paginate results in RxNet? Also I would really like to get a stream of results i.e the contents of each page flattened to a single observable,which I could return from this function,but I've no idea how to achieve this.

```
private void FetchStringParents(int checklist_id)
    {
        /*Setup the filter to the endpoint such that string parents returned are those associated with the passed checklist*/

        Filter base_filter = new Filter("checklist_id", "eq", checklist_id.ToString());
        NestedFilter nested_filter = new NestedFilter("checklists", "any", base_filter);
        Filters filt = new Filters();
        filt.filters.Add(nested_filter);
        string sp_query_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filt);
        int result_count = 0;
        int page = 1;
        var paged_observable = Observable.DoWhile(
            //At least once create an observable on the api endpoint
            Observable.Defer(() => NetworkService_ChecklistStringParentService.GetInstance.GetChecklistStringParents(6,
             this.cached_auth.Auth_Token, sp_query_json, page)),
        /*boolean function which determines if we should hit the api again   (if we got back a non empty result the last time)*/
        () => result_count > 0)
        .Subscribe(
             st =>
             {
                 //on successful receipt of a page
                 Debug.WriteLine("Success");
                 page++;//update page so that the next observable created is created on page++
                 result_count = st.BODY.Count;//update result_count (we will stop listening on a count of 0)
             },
              _e =>
              {
                  Debug.WriteLine("Fail");
              });
    }
```

**Update: Solution**

```
private IObservable<Resp_ChecklistStringParent> StreamParents(int checklist_id)
    {
        Filter base_filter = new Filter("checklist_id", "eq", checklist_id.ToString());
        NestedFilter nested_filter = new NestedFilter("checklists", "any", base_filter);
        Filters filt = new Filters();
        filt.filters.Add(nested_filter);
        string sp_query_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filt);
        return Observable.Create<List<Resp_ChecklistStringParent>>(async (obs, ct) =>
        {
            int pageIdx = 1;
            //for testing page size is set to 1 on server
            int pageSize = 1;
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //Pass in cancellation token here?
                var page = await NetworkService_ChecklistStringParentService.GetInstance.GetChecklistStringParents(6,
                this.cached_auth.Auth_Token, sp_query_json, pageIdx++);
                obs.OnNext(page.BODY);
                if (page.BODY.Count < pageSize)
                {
                    obs.OnCompleted();
                    break;
                }
            }
        })
        .SelectMany(page => page);
    }
```

Comment: Your code uses a hodge-podge of state and Rx that seems rather odd. There should be a very clean Rx way of doing this, but it really seems like we need to know the signature of `GetChecklistStringParents` to be able to help.

Comment: And all of the associated type definitions. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi, thanks for taking a look. I've added those details to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample that shows how you could stream data both with `IEnumerable<T>` and `IObservable<T>`.
The `IEnumerable<T>` sample is for context and comparison.

I am not using your data type as I dont think it has any relevance to the question (hoping that is ok).

*Linqpad script*

```
void Main()
{
    var enumerableItems = GetItemsSync();
    foreach (var element in enumerableItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Received all synchronous items");
    StreamItems().Subscribe(
        element => Console.WriteLine(element),
        () => Console.WriteLine("Received all asynchronous items"));
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public IObservable<string> StreamItems()
{
    return Observable.Create<string[]>(async (obs, ct) =>
    {
        var pageIdx = 0;
        var pageSize = 3;
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Pass in cancellation token here?
            var page = await GetPageAsync(pageIdx++, pageSize);
            obs.OnNext(page);
            if (page.Length < pageSize)
            {
                obs.OnCompleted();
                break;
            }
        }
    })
    .SelectMany(page => page);
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetItemsSync()
{
    return GetPagesSync().SelectMany(page => page);
}
public IEnumerable<string[]> GetPagesSync()
{
    var i = 0;
    var pageSize = 3;
    while (true)
    {
        var page = GetPageSync(i++, pageSize);
        yield return page;
        if (page.Length < pageSize)
            yield break;
    }
}
private static string[] _fakeData = new string[]{
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "Five",
    "six",
    "Se7en",
    "Eight"
};
public string[] GetPageSync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var idx = pageSize * pageIndex;
    var bufferSize = Math.Min(pageSize, _fakeData.Length-idx);
    var buffer = new string[bufferSize];
    Array.Copy(_fakeData, idx, buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    return buffer;
}
public Task<string[]> GetPageAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    //Just to emulate an Async method (like a web request).
    return Task.FromResult(GetPageSync(pageIndex, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, have adapted this for my own nefarious purposes. Thanks also for http://www.introtorx.com/ without which my fumbling would be even more amusing.